# Pandas groupby + resample/TimeGrouper for change over months from start

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of employee salary data (sample as follows) where 'Date' refers to when the employee's salary became effective:

```
Employee    Date        Salary
PersonA     1/1/2016    $50000 
PersonB     3/5/2014    $65000 
PersonB     3/1/2015    $75000 
PersonB     3/1/2016    $100000 
PersonC     5/15/2010   $75000 
PersonC     6/3/2011    $100000 
PersonC     3/10/2012   $110000 
PersonC     9/5/2012    $130000 
PersonC     3/1/2013    $150000 
PersonC     3/1/2014    $200000
```

In this example, PersonA started this year at $50,000 and PersonC has been with the company for a while and has received several increases since his start on 5/15/2010.

I need to convert the `Date` column to `Months from Start`, on an individual employee basis, where `Months from Start` will be in increments of `m` months (specified by me).  For example, for PersonB, assuming `m=12`, the result would be:

```
Employee    Months From Start   Salary
PersonB     0                   $65000 
PersonB     12                  $65000 
PersonB     24                  $75000
```

This means that at month 0 (employment start), PersonB had a salary of $65,000; 12 months later his salary was $65,000, and 24 months later his salary was $75,000.  Note that the next increment (36 months) would **NOT** appear on the transformed dataframe for PersonB because that duration exceeds the duration of PersonB's employment (it would be in the future).

Note again that I want to be able to adjust `m` to any month increment.  If I wanted increments of 6 months (`m=6`), the result would be:

```
Employee    Months From Start   Salary
PersonB     0                   $65000 
PersonB     6                   $65000 
PersonB     12                  $65000 
PersonB     18                  $75000 
PersonB     24                  $100000 
PersonB     30                  $100000
```

As a final step, I would also like to include the employee's salary as of *today* on the transformed dataframe.  Using PersonB again, and assuming `m=6`, this means that the results would be:

```
Employee    Months From Start   Salary
PersonB     0                   $65000 
PersonB     6                   $65000 
PersonB     12                  $65000 
PersonB     18                  $75000 
PersonB     24                  $100000 
PersonB     30                  $100000 
PersonB     32.92               $100000 <--added (today is 32.92 months from start)
```

**Question:** is there a programmatic way (I assume using at least one of: `groupby`, `resample`, or `TimeGrouper`) to achieve the desired dataframe described above?

Note: you can assume all employees are active (have not left the company).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to the provided answers.  Unfortunately, all answers are a little 'off' and didn't quite achieve the goal.  I ended up nesting two `for` loops within list comprehensions to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine group_by and resample to do it. To use resample, you need to have the date as index.

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df.drop('Date',axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

Then:

```
df.groupby('Employee').resample('6m').pad()
```

In this case, I'm using 6 month periods. Notice that it will get the last day of each month, I hope it's not gonna be a problem.
Then you will have:

```
    Employee   Date      Salary
0   PersonA 2016-01-31   $50000
1   PersonB 2014-03-31   $65000
2   PersonB 2014-09-30   $65000
3   PersonB 2015-03-31   $75000
4   PersonB 2015-09-30   $75000
5   PersonB 2016-03-31  $100000
6   PersonC 2010-05-31   $75000
7   PersonC 2010-11-30   $75000
8   PersonC 2011-05-31   $75000
9   PersonC 2011-11-30  $100000
10  PersonC 2012-05-31  $110000
11  PersonC 2012-11-30  $130000
12  PersonC 2013-05-31  $150000
13  PersonC 2013-11-30  $150000
14  PersonC 2014-05-31  $200000
```

Now you can create the "months since started" column (cumcount function checks the order in which each row appears within its group). Remember to multiply it by the number of months you're using for each period (in this case, 6):

```
df['Months since started'] = df.groupby('Employee').cumcount()*6

     Employee   Date      Salary     Months since started
0   PersonA 2016-01-31   $50000                  0
1   PersonB 2014-03-31   $65000                  0
2   PersonB 2014-09-30   $65000                  6
3   PersonB 2015-03-31   $75000                 12
4   PersonB 2015-09-30   $75000                 18
5   PersonB 2016-03-31  $100000                 24
6   PersonC 2010-05-31   $75000                  0
7   PersonC 2010-11-30   $75000                  6
8   PersonC 2011-05-31   $75000                 12
9   PersonC 2011-11-30  $100000                 18
10  PersonC 2012-05-31  $110000                 24
11  PersonC 2012-11-30  $130000                 30
12  PersonC 2013-05-31  $150000                 36
13  PersonC 2013-11-30  $150000                 42
14  PersonC 2014-05-31  $200000                 48
```

Hope it helped!

Comment: Thanks for the hints.  One problem I ran into is that within the full dataset, some employees have salaries going into effect on the same day, so setting `index` to `df.Date` violates the unique index requirement that `resample` apparently wants (I receive this error: `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`).  Let me know if you have any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `groupby`and `merge` functionalities of `DataFrames`

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([['PersonC','5/15/2010',75000],['PersonC','7/3/2011',100000],['PersonB','3/5/2014',65000],['PersonB','3/1/2015',75000],['PersonB','3/1/2016',100000]],columns=['Employee','Date','Salary'])
>>> df['Date']= pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
>>> df
  Employee       Date  Salary
0  PersonC 2010-05-15   75000
1  PersonC 2011-07-03  100000
2  PersonB 2014-03-05   65000
3  PersonB 2015-03-01   75000
4  PersonB 2016-03-01  100000
>>> satrt_date = df.groupby('Employee')['Date'].min().to_frame().rename(columns={'Date':'Start Date'})
>>> satrt_date['Employee'] = satrt_date.index 
>>> df = df.merge(satrt_date,how='left', on= 'Employee')
>>> df['Months From Start'] = df['Date']-df['Start Date']
>>> df['Months From Start'] = df['Months From Start'].apply(lambda x: x.days)
>>> df['Months From Start']= df['Months From Start'].apply(lambda x: (x/30) - (x/30)%6)
>>> df
  Employee       Date  Salary Start Date  Months From Start
0  PersonC 2010-05-15   75000 2010-05-15                  0
1  PersonC 2011-07-03  100000 2010-05-15                 12
2  PersonB 2014-03-05   65000 2014-03-05                  0
3  PersonB 2015-03-01   75000 2014-03-05                 12
4  PersonB 2016-03-01  100000 2014-03-05                 24
```

Here you can replace `6` with a variable called `m` and assign arbitrary values to it

Answer (score 1):

OK, so for the first part of the answer I would do something like this...

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Employee': ['PersonA', 'PersonB', 'PersonB', 'PersonB', 'PersonC', 'PersonC', 'PersonC', 'PersonC', 'PersonC', 'PersonC'], 
    'Date': ['1/1/2016', '3/5/2014', '3/1/2015', '3/1/2016', '5/15/2010', '6/3/2011', '3/10/2012', '9/5/2012', '3/1/2013', '3/1/2014'], 
    'Salary': [50000 , 65000 , 75000 , 100000 , 75000 , 100000 , 110000 , 130000 , 150000 , 200000]
})

df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

m = 6
emp_groups = df.groupby('Employee')
df['months_from_start'] = df.Date - emp_groups.Date.transform(min)
df.months_from_start = df.months_from_start.dt.days / 30 // m * m
```

`m` can be whatever you want it to be. I am calculating the days between the `min` date then dividing by the approximate amount of days in a month and then doing a little bit of integer division to "round off" to the window size you want.

This will give you something like this...

```
        Date Employee  Salary  months_from_start
0 2016-01-01  PersonA   50000                  0
1 2014-03-05  PersonB   65000                  0
2 2015-03-01  PersonB   75000                 12
3 2016-03-01  PersonB  100000                 24
4 2010-05-15  PersonC   75000                  0
5 2011-06-03  PersonC  100000                 12
6 2012-03-10  PersonC  110000                 18
7 2012-09-05  PersonC  130000                 24
8 2013-03-01  PersonC  150000                 30
9 2014-03-01  PersonC  200000                 42
```

The second part is a little tricky. I would create a new df and concat to the first...

```
last_date_df = emp_groups.last()
last_date_df.months_from_start = (last_date_df.Date - emp_groups.first().Date).dt.days / 30
last_date_df.reset_index(inplace=True)

pd.concat([df, last_date_df], axis=0)
```

getting you...

```
        Date Employee  Salary  months_from_start
0 2016-01-01  PersonA   50000           0.000000
1 2014-03-05  PersonB   65000           0.000000
2 2015-03-01  PersonB   75000          12.000000
3 2016-03-01  PersonB  100000          24.000000
4 2010-05-15  PersonC   75000           0.000000
5 2011-06-03  PersonC  100000          12.000000
6 2012-03-10  PersonC  110000          18.000000
7 2012-09-05  PersonC  130000          24.000000
8 2013-03-01  PersonC  150000          30.000000
9 2014-03-01  PersonC  200000          42.000000
0 2016-01-01  PersonA   50000           0.000000
1 2016-03-01  PersonB  100000          24.233333
2 2014-03-01  PersonC  200000          46.200000
```